# NavigatorIOS between files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an iOS app with react-native and now I'm stuck trying to load another view of my app, I'm gonna explain this in more deep.

I got an index view with a ListView to load a list of items, I have the code of the item will be listed in another file, so I require the file in my index view:

```
var Story = require('./story');
```

Then I have a render function:

```
renderStory: function(story) { 
  return (
    < Story story={ story } />
  ); 
},
```

And my ListView component:

```
<ListView 
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
  renderRow={this.renderStory}
  style={ styles.content } />
```

Everything working well so far. But now, I wanna do that every time you tap on a part of my "Story" item, go to another view, through NavigatorIOS (as far as I know it is the only view to navigate between views) so I've been trying to do that but I find the problem that I have my index and my item views in separate files, so I alway get errors.

I'd be very grateful if somebody can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is some code that I have in my "Story" item file:

```
var Story = React.createClass({
  gotoIndividualStory: function(){
    console.log(this.props);
    // this.props.navigator.push({
    //   title: 'Individual Story',
    //   component: Individual,
    // });
  },

  render: function() {
    var story = this.props.story;

    return (
      <View style={ styles.story }>
        <NavigatorIOS
          initialRoute={{
            component: Individual,
            title: 'List',
          }} />

        <View style={ styles.storyHeader }>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this.gotoIndividualStory() }>
            <Image style={ styles.storyImage } source={ { uri: story.image_thumb_url } } />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple different approaches you can make here.

1) Simple, but a bit inferior architecturally: Have your Story class take a property which is a function (React.PropTypes.func) - name the property "onTap" for example. This will be your callback. Then in your renderStory add the callback. it will make your renderRow look more like

```
renderRow={(rowData) =>  this.renderStory(rowData, this.onTap)}
```

and your renderStory will look more like:

```
renderStory: function(story, onTap) {
   return (<Story story={story} onTap={onTap});
}
```

and when you actually tap in the story make the callback:

```
 onTap(story)
```

2) Better architecture will be to use Flux architecture (for example)(https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) - you dispatch the click to Dispatcher as mehod, it informs local stores and they emit events that is handled by navigation view.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Jarek.

I've set the new variable on the renderRow part, also in the renderStory function, but I'm not sure where I have to use the onTap(story) code.

In the file where I have the story item, I have this part where I want to control the tap (I've edited my question with more info)

Comment: It's pretty different that you have now. You have to define NavigatorIOS view in the main class's render defined elsewhere and only from there refer Story as a part of another view (you cannot have <NavigatorIOS> rendered in the Story's render - Story should only render itself. It's the main application class's render should render <NavigatorIOS> and then inside the Navigator IOS - via initialRoute or maybe later by pushing other routes - should refer to <Story > (probably indirectly - through some List View or ScrollView).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain well before.

Actually, I've been testing with NavigatorIOS in both files, and, as I explained in my question, I always get errors no matter in which file I work.

If I define NavigatorIOS in my main class, then when I try to handle the onPress event in my story item, I get errors. I don't know how to solve this :/

Thanks.

Comment: do you think I can do it somehow?? Thanks :)